# Get series Label name to display as a text

Tags: jqplot

I have a bar chart. Please find the below code of the bar chart. Also find the attached image which is the result of the given script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
    var s2 = [7, 5, 3, 2];
    var s3 = [14, 9, 3, 8];
    var tickx = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
    plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2, s3], {
        stackSeries: true,
        captureRightClick: true,
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                highlightMouseDown: true    
            },
            pointLabels: {show: true}
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            location: 'e',
            placement: 'outside'
        },
       axes: { 
           xaxis: {
              renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
              ticks: tickx
          }
       }
    });

    $('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataRightClick', 
        function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
            $('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
        }
    ); 
});
```

On right click on the bar it will display the value of right clicked bar.

> You Right Clicked: series: 2, point: 1, data: 2,9.

Here, the value 2 in the data value (data: 2,9) is the xaxis series number. Instead of series name i would like to get the tick used in the chart.

In this above script tick given is : `["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];`

I want the output displayed as

if the user clicks the series 1 axis. result should be

> You Right Clicked: series: 2, point: 1, data: 1,7, series label: aaa.

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Antony

Comment: You are confused.  The tick "category" label you have defined as tickx is not a series name, but rather the x-axis position (this is why you are missing the 4th bar).  Did you want series labels or did you want the x position category corresponding to the click?

Answer (score 2):

Read my comment above.  If you are after the xaxis category position on the right-click, use this:

```
$('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataRightClick', 
        function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
            $('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data + ' category label: ' + plot3.axes.xaxis.ticks[pointIndex]);
        }
    );
```

In your event handler.